# Ceph Clock Skew

Tags: ntp, proxmox, ceph

I want to know where I can configure the limit of skew time for my **ceph** monitors. Also,how does CEPH throw this **clock skew** error? Specifically from which file and where can I find the file so that I can edit?

I am already running NTP and everything's working fine and I am not getting any skew errors.

I want to write a shell script from which I could get a mail when this skew error occurs or has reached a threshold of my customization.